# Controlling a host's behavior in Westworld?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

Is it really necessary to establish a wired connection between host and controlling device ?

In Season two Episode 3 we have seen that Bernard was trying to manipulate a host's behavior by establishing a wired connection . But in previous season we have seen that in many cases that it doesn't require a wired connection to do so

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it really necessary to establish a wired connection between host and controlling device ?

## No

In previous cases, such as in the production/repair/servicing areas we saw they were relying on a wireless connection of some kind.

When we see Bernard making the physical connection to the host he **specifically** says.

> **"Network's down**, but I can hard port in and give him a little attitude adjustment.

So, if the network is up it can link the controlling "pads" to the hosts but if not, a physical connection is required...just like our normal devices.